# pspell global namespace dictionary

Tags: php, dictionary, spell-checking, aspell

is it possible to create something like "a global dictionary" for pspell?

I tried a lot but i can only create a personal dictionary for languages which are installed.

Am im blind, or is there a better way than just insert a word for the global dictionary to the personal dictionary for each language?

Best Regards,
Beerweasle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone else who has a similar problem:

Now im just using an dictionary-iso of an other latin1-language that i normally wouldnt use